# Pandas: Integer date not recognized with pd.to_datetime(x)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

In the given dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd
import numexpr as ne
op_d = {'ID': [1, 2,3],'V':['F','G','H'],'AAA':[0,1,1],'E':[20141223,20190201,20170203] ,'D':['2019/02/04','2019/02/01','2019/01/01'],'DD':['2019-12-01','2016-05-31','2015-02-15'],'CurrentRate':[7.5,2,2],'NoteRate':[2,3,3],'BBB':[0,00,4],'Q1':[2,8,00],'Q2':[3,5,7],'Q3':[5,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=op_d)
df
```

if I do `pd.to_datetime(df['E'])` , it results in following:

```
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020141223
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020190201
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.020170203
Name: E, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Is this expected behavior ? If this is expected then how can I detect date from Integer field? I know if dtype is object, I can place try except block on the columns and convert them to datetime format.

Comment: You have to specify the actual format (`..., format = ...`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is necessary specify parameter `format` - `%Y%m%d` means `YYMMDD`:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['E'], format='%Y%m%d'))
0   2014-12-23
1   2019-02-01
2   2017-02-03
Name: E, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate this without specifying format? Only thing I am afraid of  is if user enters date in different format i.e. 02092020.